# SQL Query to get the workorders which skipped some lines processing

Tags: sql, sql-server, skip

As I am not expert in writing the SQL queries so want for help.

I have the below given dataset

I need to write a query to get all the workorderid's which have skipped the process and moved to next seq_no , ex:
workorderid = AW1 which has a line "open" for seq_no=30 and went ahead to "complete" for seq_no = 40

The final result set should look like below

```
Workorderid
----------- 
AW1  
AW3
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One method simply uses conditional aggregation:

```
select workorderid
from t
group by workorderid
having (max(case when status = 'Open' then seq_no end) <
        max(case when status = 'Complete' then seq_no end)
       )
```

That is, is there a `'Complete'` after the last `'Open'`, based on `seq_no`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another one using EXISTS:

```
SELECT t1.workorderid
FROM t t1
WHERE t1.status = 'Open'
AND EXISTS
(SELECT 1
 FROM t t2
 WHERE t2.workorderid = t1.workorderid
 AND t2.seq_no > t1.seq_no
 AND t2.status = 'Complete')
```